# Wordpress jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I found a tutorial online for a jQuery accordion:

[jQuery accordion Tutorial](http://cssdeck.com/labs/simple-jquery-accordion)

The issue i am having is getting that to work within Wordpress. I have done everything in enque the script properly using wp_enqueue_script in the theme functions file. which I have done several times before but this just does not seem to be working. I added this script:

```
$(function($) {
  var allAccordions = $('.accordion div.data');
  var allAccordionItems = $('.accordion .accordion-item');
  $('.accordion > .accordion-item').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('open'))
    {
      $(this).removeClass('open');
      $(this).next().slideUp("slow");
    }
    else
    {
      allAccordions.slideUp("slow");
      allAccordionItems.removeClass('open');
      $(this).addClass('open');
      $(this).next().slideDown("slow");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

to a separate .js file and enqued it but it will not work. correct me if I am wrong what I would have to do is create a initialization of that specific script as well. Could anyone assist me in doing so?

Thank you in advanced :)

Comment: Try `jQuery(function($) ...` instead of `$(function($) ...`

Comment: Ok, I posted as answer below.

Comment: I did not see it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jQuery(function($) ...` instead of `$(function($) ...`

The `$` is used elsewhere, so you need `jQuery` at the start of the DOM ready function.  Then the `$` keyword is passed into the function where you can safely use it inside.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `jQuery` instead of `$` in Wordpress.

This is how you do it:

```
    jQuery(function($) {
  var allAccordions = $('.accordion div.data');
  var allAccordionItems = $('.accordion .accordion-item');
  $('.accordion > .accordion-item').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('open'))
    {
      $(this).removeClass('open');
      $(this).next().slideUp("slow");
    }
    else
    {
      allAccordions.slideUp("slow");
      allAccordionItems.removeClass('open');
      $(this).addClass('open');
      $(this).next().slideDown("slow");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress users [`$.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) to refer to jQuery as `jQuery`. Your code is referring to it as `$` but also passing the same as a function argument, so within the function you have overridden the `$` global containing jQuery. This function is the same as [`jQuery(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) and runs when the DOM is finished loading.

```
jQuery(function(){
    var allAccordions = jQuery('.accordion div.data');
 // etc... with jQuery known as jQuery
});
```

If you want to refer to jQuery as `$` within your function, you can do so by using the following syntax to pass jQuery into your anonymous function arguments, where it is then know as `$` in your function scope. This will run immediately and not wait for the DOM to load.

```
(function($) {
     var allAccordions = $('.accordion div.data'); 
     // etc... with jQuery known as $
})(jQuery);
```

If you want to refer to jQuery as `$` but have it wait until the DOM loads, use `jQuery.ready()` or shorthand `jQuery(callback)`.

```
jQuery(function(){
    (function($) {
         var allAccordions = $('.accordion div.data'); 
         // etc... with jQuery known as $
    })(jQuery);
});
```